# How to set valueFrom/valueTo of objectAnimator according to all kinds of width/height devices screen

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-animation, objectanimator

android.app.fragment's custom animation can only support property animator
by transaction.setCustomAnimations(), the animation such as

```
<set>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="X"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="-720"
    android:valueTo="0" />
</set>
```

but android.support.v4.fragment's custom animation can support frame/tween animation by transaction.setCustomAnimations(), the animation such as

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="false">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.7" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%p"
        android:pivotY="50%p"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9" />
</set>
```

Now i have used the android.app.fragment in my project, so the fragment's switching animation can only use objectAnimator, but the problem is how to set the valueFrom/valueTo according to all kinds of width/height screen ?

Comment: What might help you is how to set objectAnimator to use a percentage or fraction of screen. There are a number of solutions for this on stackoverflow as well as several blogs: http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/

Comment: I have resolved it  by override the fragment's root layout view setXFraction/getXFraction methods.  The blogs you given are also very helpful for me. Thanks very much !